# Do we lie to ourselves when creating a mock for a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have just started learning all about unit testing since yesterday and today was reading about Mocks and `NSub` in particular.
The problem I have is that I don't get the philosophy and way of thinking behind it.  So for example reading my book came to this:

```
[Test]
public void Returns_ByDefault_WorksForHardCodedArgument()
{
IFileNameRules fakeRules = Substitute.For<IFileNameRules>();

fakeRules.IsValidLogFileName(Arg.Any<String>())
.Returns(true);

Assert.IsTrue(fakeRules.IsValidLogFileName("anything.txt"));

}
```

OK so first we make a fake object to represent the interface of the actual class that we have a actual method in it that does some actual work. Then we call that method but we also tell it to return true.
Then we assert it to see if it is returning true  ? Well we just told it one line before that return true! now we test it is returning true! they we say ok good passed? 
I don't get it! To me feel like this: Teacher tell the kid in order to pass the exam answer yes to this question if asked, then goes and asks that question and kid says yes and exam is passed?

Comment: You shouldn't mock or stub the class that you want to test. Only its dependencies.

Comment: @YacoubMassad It is in Roy's unit testing book, so he ahs just used this silly thign to teach us the syntax ?

Comment: Is this an example from the book? As is?

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes, Art of Unit Testing, Chapter 5 , Section 3 !

Comment: .. and does the book version use `Arg.Any<String>`?

Comment: @stuartd yes, I COPY PASTED !

Comment: @Bohn wow. I have this book, and found it very useful. But in this case it's only the mocking framework that's being tested, which seems odd.

Comment: Most probably the author is making a statement about how the mocking framework works. The name of the test suggests this too. He is testing the `Returns` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments on this question, this test is likely demonstrating how the mocking library works. For our test code we are extremely unlikely (partial mocks being a potential exception) to mock out the class we want to test. Instead we may want to mock out some things the code uses, in order to get more deterministic tests, or faster tests, or tests that simulate rare events, etc.

To your direct question, yes I guess we are sort lying to ourselves when we mock out dependencies for a test. We are saying "let's pretend that our dependency does X, then check our code does Y". Now it is possible the dependency never actually does "X". To me, the aim of mocking is to start off with this fiction, then test our dependency and make sure it actually does do "X", to the point where the fiction ends up matching reality.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of testing is to check every single way a method could possibly behave. If you tell the method a true statement and it returns false. Obviously something is wrong with the method you wrote. Sometimes the most complex issues can be solved by finding simple mistakes in your code. (In this case checking to see if the method will actually return true when asked to return true.) IF it fails to do so. You done messed up.

Comment: how is it testng the acutal method? it is saying fakeRules.IsValidLogFileName ... and the line above that told it to return true always !

Comment: in the specific case OP has posted, it's _only the mocking framework which is tested_ - a pattern I have seen over and over again with people new to tests or devs being asked to write unit tests when they don't understand what the idea behind them is.